# How to get custom entity data in custom page

Tags: 8, entities, database

i have created Event entity, and I have custom page.

I want to load ALL Entity rows and then use it in my template.

This is the way everyone is prsenting, but i don't know how can i get NID value

`$events = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('event')->load($nid);`

Using Symfony i could do this like:

```
$events = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Event::class)->findAll();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution

```
$storage = Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('event');

$nids = Drupal::entityQuery('event')->execute();
//Load all nids
$events = $storage->loadMultiple($nids);
//You can also use
$events = $storage->loadMultiple();
```

Comment: An empty loadMultiple() loads all entities by default: `$events = $storage->loadMultiple();`